# Anyway to make timepicker pop up match the full width of parent form control?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, styling, mui-x

```html
 <FormControl fullWidth>
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
        <TimePicker
             views={["hours", "minutes", "seconds"]}
             label={t("StrategyManager.Select_Time")}
             value={timer}
             onChange={(selectedTime) => handleTimeSelection(selectedTime, "timer")}
             ampm={false}
             />
   </LocalizationProvider>
</FormControl>
```

[image]

At the moment I have the above component in react and typescript using MUI version v6.16.1 but the popper only sits to the left of the parent field.

Ideally I'd like it to span the full width of the form control with equal width for each hours / minutes / seconds columns but I can't seem to target the wrapper.

Any help with styling this component would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a way to do this, you have to use [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)  to get the input width(with the help of `useRef`). and then use it to set the time picker dropdown width, see my codesandbox example below

[image: Edit interesting-glitter-t9qxrl]

there are a few things you should note:

- I used `desktopModeMediaQuery=""` to deactivate the [mobile variant](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/time-picker/#available-components:%7E:text=Mobile%20variant,-Responsive%20variant) of the time picker, because I'm overriding layout styles which breaks the mobile variant
- the width won't update if you resize the window, I know this won't likely happen with real users but just fyi

I honestly feel like this solution is very *hacky* so unless you **really** need it and didn't find a better alternative

Comment: This works though it does cause an error if the timepicker isn't initially loaded on the screen. Though I agree it doesn't seem like the most ideal way to go about styling the dropdown. I appreciate the answer though!

Comment: what did you change that throws an error for you?

Comment: The time picker is contained within a drawer meaning it is only loaded under certain conditions and this means the line setInputWidth(timePicker.width); initially comes back as being undefined as there is no timepicker to be found initially. 

Like you mentioned the solution works but is rather hacky so I think for now I'll leave the styling of the the timepicker as is I think!

Comment: I think you can get around that by creating a custom `TimePicker` and move the `useEffect` that calculate the width there